# How can add 2 actions when i try to act for a name and make a mini menu?

Tags: java, actionevent

You can find my code at: http://pastebin.com/GGzKLeF4

How can I have the action event `e` in both the menu and the asking for a name and if that is not possible how can I have both of them.

**Error:**

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at listener_p_2.Listener_P_2.main(Listener_P_2.java:9)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - method                              actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) is already defined in class   listener_p_2.AcrionListener_gui
at listener_p_2.AcrionListener_gui.<clinit>(AcrionListener_gui.java:51)
... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

few ways to solve it. drop the method duplicate and manual event creation in the first place and get an IDE - e.g. community edition of intellij idea

1) lambda for event handling (hope you're on java 8)

```
    exit.addActionListener(e -> {
        System.out.println("Event source " + e.getSource().getClass());
        System.exit(0);
    });
```

2) dispatching all the events through the same method

```
exit.addActionListener(this);
```

and in the `actionPerformed` method

```
    } else if (exit.equals(e.getSource())) {
        ...
    }
```